# Server apache-tomcat-9.0.55 at localhost failed to start -- no idea what I can do to resolve this

Tags: java, tomcat

I am having a really big issue that I would really appreciate help on. Essentially, my class project that was a dynamic web page got completely messed up. I was able to recover some of the files, but have to start a new maven-archtype-webpage and restructure the project so I can copy and paste these files in.

I am trying to run a sample index.jsp page that says "hello world" on apache 9.0.55, and it is not working. I get an error that reads "Server apache-tomcat-9.0.55 at localhost failed to start.". The deeper error messages on the console say

````
'''
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3f363cf5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3f363cf5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/Users/teutaelazaj/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Job_Portal] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:762)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 30 more

Dec 03, 2022 2:01:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Dec 03, 2022 2:01:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Dec 03, 2022 2:01:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
```
````

I was not having this issue at all before and I am honestly at a loss for what I can do. This is my POM.XML file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.prog</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectCUS1156</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ProjectCUS1156 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>ProjectCUS1156</finalName>
  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

This is how my project is currently structured
[image: projectview]

And this is what my java build path and target runtimes look like
[image: java build path]

[image: targeted runtimes]

Any help at all would be extremely appreciated. I will make sure to mark your response as correct and upvote. Thank you so much

Comment: I have also tried changing the port numbers to see if that fixes anything but unfortunately it doesn’t

Comment: Sorry you're having difficulties with a school project.  That can be frustrating and stressful.  Your web.xml file and your target directories do not look quite right.  I would recommend starting over with a new clean project.  Here is a reasonable tutorial on getting a spring boot application running.  I recommend following Option 3 since it forces you to do all the steps yourself:  https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-spring-boot-project-with-eclipse-and-ma

Comment: And a friendly nudge to consider using git/github for committing and storing your work when it is working (at least just a little bit).

Comment: @hooknc thank you so much for the kind words!! Luckily I have fixed this issue. Yes, definitely a huge lesson learned! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrealy tryed to figered out what line of code is wrong in your pom.
the simple way to fix it, replace everything
[(4.1. Creating the POM)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.first-application.pom)
and add dependency web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you very much! I was somehow able to fix it on my own. I just right clicked on the server component and readded apache tomcat! Thank you very much